# Make A3 sheet PDF of multiple page A4 inDesign doc

Tags: pdf, cs5, adobe-acrobat

I need to output A3 PDF sheets with multiple A4 pages from Indesign CS5 (So an editor can mark up by hand, the order of many small text based labels for an exhibition). Tried making a postscript but my Acrobat just distilled straight back into A4 single page PDF.... same result as exporting as a PDF from InDesign....

There's a potential great answer to my question - how I thought I could do it prior to not being able to (!) BUT: problem is my Acrobat (X) doesn't have any print option except MY printer! - there is no PDF printer there - after selecting [print], there is nothing in printer list except my Canon, & if I select PDF button from bottom left of [printer] dialogue there are various PDF / .ps options, but all say they are not supported, or such like: 'Saving a PDF file when printing is not supported. Instead, choose File > Save.... well I don't need to save the single A4 pages again thank you!!

Any suggestions...? seems crazy to be able to print multiple A4 pages to A3 hard copy sheets from Acrobat, but not generate the same as a digital file.... Am I missing something & being rather stupid??!! Any suggestion would be most appreciated. Thank you. Anna

Comment: So the problem is that you can't find a way to export a pdf from Indesing? `File > Export...` or `Cmd+E`.

Answer (score 3):

are the original A4 pages in your InDesign document next to each other in the Pages palette? If so, you should be able to export as 'Spreads' in the 'Export Adobe PDF' dialogue box. This option is available in the 'General' section, in the 'Pages' sub section.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Like Cheli says, you can check 'spreads' when you're exporting from InDesign if your document is set up with Facing Pages. 
But another way is to place your existing A4 PDF pages 2-up in a new A3 InDesign document, and export that to PDF.

Answer (score 0):

InDesign now has an Adjust Layout tool.

Press Alt+Shift+P, select your page size and you're good to go!